# Scraping HTML with Rvest: Cannot pull text

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape text from the following website: https://redditsearch.io/?term=&dataviz=false&aggs=false&subreddits=wallstreetbets&searchtype=posts,comments&search=true&start=1616275216&end=1618867216&size=100.

Basically, I want to pull all from text with the class *comment* on the page, but no text is returned.

This what I've tried so far:

```
url <- "https://redditsearch.io/?term=&dataviz=false&aggs=false&subreddits=wallstreetbets&searchtype=posts,comments&search=true&start=1616275216&end=1618867216&size=100"

page_source <- read_html(url)

comments <- page_source %>%
  html_node('#results-container') %>%
  html_nodes('.comment') %>%
  html_text()

comments
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Press F12 in browser, then look in the network tab, press F5 to refresh that webpage, then look for the request that starts with `https://elastic.pushshift.io/rc/comments`

Comment: to support others in helping you, please confirm that page_source <- read_html(url) returns content that you want to break down into nodes and extract your text.